# Test which symbol of a list depend on some variable

Tags: list-manipulation, symbols

Given a list of symbols, say `{y[x],z[x],k}`

Is there a way to sort which depend on `x` and which don't ?
Applied to the above list, the method would give:

`{y[x],z[x]}`

and `{k}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen `FreeQ[]`?

Comment: Consider also `GatherBy[]`.

Comment: I guess `FreeQ[#, x] & /@{y[x], k, x}` could be enough for what I have in mind. Although, is there a way to explicitly check for `[x]`'s presence and rather than `x` ?

Comment: @jrekier `_[x]`.

Comment: @Kuba Will this pick `f[x,z]` also?  It gets tricky? Function that depends on `x` and other variables?

Comment: @Nasser I simply provided what was asked for in the comment above. The "dependency" was not defined by OP so there is no point in discussion :) But you are probably right of course :)